# Add Namespace to xml file

Tags: c#, addition, xml-namespaces

I have a xml file to which I want to add predefined namespeces.. Following is the code:

```
private const string uri = "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/";
private static readonly List<string> namespaces = new List<string> { "lun" };

public static XElement AddNameSpaceAndLoadXml(string xmlFile) {
    var nameSpaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
    // add custom namespace to the manager and take the prefix from the collection
    namespaces.ToList().ForEach(name => {
         nameSpaceManager.AddNamespace(name, string.Concat(uri, name));
    });

    XmlParserContext parserContext = new XmlParserContext(null, nameSpaceManager, null, XmlSpace.Default);
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(@xmlFile, null, parserContext)) {
        return XElement.Load(reader);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the resulting xml in memory does not show the correct namespaces added. Also, they are not added at the root but are added next to the tag. Xml added below. 
In the xml it is showing `p3:read_data` while should be `lun:read_data`.

How do i get to add the namespace on the root tag and not get the incorrect name.

Sample Input xml:

```
<config file-suffix="perf">
 <overview-graph title="Top 5 LUN Reads" max-series="5" remove-series="1">
  <counters lun:read_data=""/>
 </overview-graph>
</config>
```

Output xml expected:

```
<config file-suffix="perf" xmlns:lun="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/lun">
 <overview-graph title="Top 5 LUN Reads" max-series="5" remove-series="1">
  <counters lun:read_data=""  /> 
 </overview-graph>
</config>
```

Output that is coming using the above code:

```
<config file-suffix="perf" >
 <overview-graph title="Top 5 LUN Reads" max-series="5" remove-series="1">
  <counters p3:read_data=""  xmlns:p3="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/lun"/> 
 </overview-graph>
</config>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're really trying to do. You've shown "sample XML" but it's not obvious whether that's the input or the output. Please show sample input and desired output. You can definitely do this without using `XmlNamespaceManager`.

Comment: why you wrote `namespaces.ToList().Foreach...` namespaces is already a liat so you can write `namespaces.Foreach...`

Comment: Updated the input, output xml and the xml generated using the code..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a better way, but adding the namespace manually seems to work.

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(@xmlFile, null, parserContext)) {
    var newElement = XElement.Load(reader);
    newElement.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "lun", string.Concat(uri, "lun")));
    return newElement;
}
```

I don't know offhand a way to generalize this however (obviously you can add the whole set by enumerating it, but outputting only used namespaces might be interesting).